# JFileChooser equivalent in Android

Tags: java, android

So Android doesn't have these Swing components. I know how to implement a JFileChooser in pure Java, but since I'm a newbie in Android app development, I don't know a single thing.

In pure Java, it is very simple

```
private class SwingFileChooser extends JFileChooser {
  private FileNameExtensionFilter filter;
  protected void chooseFiles() {
    filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("(*.java)", "java");
    this.setFileFilter(filter);
    this.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    this.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    int returnVal = this.showOpenDialog(rootPane);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      String file = this.getSelectedFile().getName();
      System.out.println("You choose the file: " + file);
    }
  }
}
```

I've searched and even watch some tutorial, but they are using their own library to create it which I found complicated for beginners like me.

Is there a simple one like in the pure Java with those file extension filter that also display in dialog form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```